# JQuery - Page fade out and fade in

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

There is a Master page with a logout button, few web pages, and a login page which does not use this master.

Trying to acheive this - When user clicks on logout, the current page will fade out into the login page. If it morphs into the login page, that would be great.

What's happening is,

1. The fade out applies only for home page but not for other pages. All of these use the master. The Home page is in the root directory. The others are in different folder. Is it necessary to link the jquery src for all pages.

**MASTER PAGE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#lnkLogout").click(function(){
     $("#form1").fadeOut("slow");         
  });
});
</script>

<form id = "form1" runat="server">     
 <asp:LinkButton id="lnkLogout" runat="server" Text="Logout" >
 </asp:LinkButton>
 <div id ="divContent">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will always get the 'break' as you are loading a new page.

The only way to achieve your 'super-smmmoootttthhhhhh' effect would be to pre-load the log-in form via ajax and then run your fade-in fade-out technique. (well not the only way but gives you the idea - your 'break' is from a page-load.)

Comment: You have a tricky scenario to be fair - you can use async ajax calls while your log-out code is running - storing the page data in a variable. Security wise you will have to be careful as you cannot physically send the user to login.aspx so make sure you have closed off all sessions, etc.

Comment: Yes - call your log-out code as you would - but just before it (in the click event) add a ajax call to download the login page - append this to a div or store it in a div - after your log-out code you would do fade-out on current page - add a div (full screen size) with your log-in form and fade that in. Bare in mind that any js etc. will also have to be included - it is quite messy and a lot to get your head around so I would recommend trying it with a practice page first to get the process steps right in your head.

Comment: Looks ok - does it work? Also because I cannot see time-out script etc. I cannot check it is secure.

Comment: You need to debug and find which bits aren't working - my guess is either javascript error (check console -f12 in chrome - then console) or that your loading the wrong page - check that url works. Debugging is simply checking each step so check that the div actually loads the page (and has dimensions) etc.

Comment: I just removed "linear" and the transition looks ok for me now. But the 2nd issue persists. The fadeout applies only to the home page, which is in the root directory. It snt for other pages which are in another folder. Why?. It just fades out and flashes the same page again.

Comment: try adding a background-color to #divLoadPage and a min-height and min-width of 500px; - if it shows then your URL is wrong.

Comment: Oh. Not using divLoadPage anymore. The master has fadeout at logout click and the login has fade in JS at page load. So its all good. Just that it is not working for other pages that are not in root directory

Comment: You mean in jquery. Im sorry but as you see, there is no need to load login into a div now, so there is nowhere i type a url there

Comment: yet again I am trying to ehlp you blind here - the 'best guess' to solve a problem with something not working in one directory but in the others is that one of your relative paths (a relative path being one that is /page.aspx) is not working on those other pages. This is fixed by going up or down a directory - or more easily by using a fixed URL - press f12 if using chrome and check the 'console' for errors.

Comment: Thank you Graham. The only place I'm using a url here is inside logout_click - response.redirect("~/Login.aspx"); This works for all pages in app when not using the fade. And no errors in console.